# Which game shows on your games played list when you put the disc in for Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 Remix

Tags: kingdom-hearts-1.5-remix

The Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 Remix for PS3 has three games on one disc (Kingdom Hearts Final Mix HD, Kingdom Hearts Re: Chain of Memories HD, and Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days HD [this one is actually just the cutscenes from the game]).  When you put in the disc, the first screen gives you the option of selecting which of the three games to play.  My question is, which game will show on my games played list if I just put the 1.5 Remix disc in?  If I just watch the cutscenes for 358/2 Days, then will that be the only one of the three games that shows on my games played list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, at least in my case, KINGDOM HEARTS 358/2 Days showed on my games played list from just putting the disk in and going to the main screen (WITHOUT having launched any game from the main menu).  It seems like that game shows on your games played list no matter what and the other two games will only show if you choose them from the main menu.

Comment: I launched KHFM right away, so I can't corroborate on 358/2 Days showing up by launching the disc alone, but I did notice that it appeared in my trophy list without having started it.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the games are treated as a separate game, so yes, `KINGDOM HEARTS 358/2 Days` will be shown as last played game, and other will not be shown as played until you run then from game select screen.